# Upload files to the specific Dropbox account on Android

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

The Dropbox SDK let user upload the files to their own account.

I want to buy a business account which have 1 TB storage.

The let other account upload the files to this account programmatically.

Anyone has an idea?

May be upload to user's own account then share it to the specific account.

But I don't know how to share to specific account programmatically.

I also found this method

```
public DropboxAPI.DropboxLink share(String path) throws DropboxException
```

but it seem to return the dropbox link.

What I really need is to upload in to the specific account and not leave any file in the client 's phone.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be upload to user's own account then share it to the specific account.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#shares